# Show that the relative topology on $B=\{(x,y) : x=y \}$ is not the discrete one.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $\mathcal{B}$ be a collection of half open rectangles in $\Bbb R^2$. Show that the relative topology $\tau_A$ on the line $A=\{(x,y) : x+y=0 \}$ is the discrete one and show that the relative topology on $B=\{(x,y) : x=y \}$ is *not* the discrete one.

Consider $O \in \tau_A$ and $x \in O$. By definition $O=A \cap U$ for $U$ open in $\Bbb R^2$. Since the basis consists of half open rectangles we have that $$O = A \cap ([x,b) \times [x,d)), \ b,d \in \Bbb R$$ is open, but $A \cap ([x,b) \times [x,d))=\{x\}$ so the singletons are open making the topology the discrete one.

Consider now $O \in \tau_B$ and $x \in O$. I think that by similar argument we get that $O=B \cap ([x,b) \times [x,d))=\{x\}$ but I think that this is both closed and open. Wouldn't this also make it the discrete topology?

Comment: For any space $X$ the diagonal $\{(x,y) \in X^2\mid y=x\}$ is homeomorphic to $X$ itself.

Comment: Make a picture, then you can tell the difference at a glance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You don't have $B\cap\bigl([x,b)\times[x,d)\bigr)=\{x\}$. In fact,$$B\cap\bigl([x,b)\times[x,d)\bigr)=\{(y,y)\mid x\leqslant y<\min\{b,d\}\}.$$

Comment: For the first part $A \cap ([x,b) \times [x,d))=\{x\}$ should be correct since we're including the point $x$ in the intervals?

Comment: Sure. The first part is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x,-x)$ be an arbitrary point of $A$.

Then $A \cap \left([x,x+1) \times [-x,-x+1)\right) = \{(x,-x)\}$ showing that the point is isolated in $A$:

If $(z,-z) \in \left([x,x+1) \times [-x,-x+1)\right)$ then $x \le z < x+1$ and also $-x\le -z < -x+1$ so $x \le z$ from the first and $x \ge z$ from the second (after inversion) so $x=z$.

OTOH: for any space $X$ the map $\Delta:x \to (x,x)$ is also $\text{id}_X \times \text{id}_X$ and hence continuous and 1-1 and is a homeomorphism of $X$ with $\Delta_X = \Delta[X]$ (as any projection is its continuous inverse).

So $B$ is in fact homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$ in the half-open interval topology (aka the right facing Sorgenfrey line). This argument does not work for $A$ as $x \to-x$ is *not* continuous on the reals in this topology..